# Lower bound for $\frac{x_{kn}}{x_n}$, where $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is non-increasing, in [0,1] and $x_n\ge\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a non-increasing sequence in [0,1], (i.e. $x_n\ge x_{n+1},n\in\mathbb{N} $), such that $x_n\ge\frac{1}{n},n\in\mathbb{N} $.

If we fix $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is there necessarily a lower bound c>0 for the fractions $\frac{x_{kn}}{x_n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

I was thinking that if it is true then maybe $\frac{x_{kn}}{x_n}\ge\frac{1}{k}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counterexample is given by $x_n=1/m!$ for $m!\leqslant n<(m+1)!$ (for each integer $m>0$).

Indeed, if $k>1$ and $m\geqslant k$, then for  $n=m!/k$ we have $x_{kn}=1/m!$ and $x_n=1/(m-1)!$ since clearly $(m-1)!\leqslant n<m!$, so that $x_{kn}/x_n=1/m$ at this value of $n$. Now take a "large" $m$.